# App thinning for video resources on iOS

Tags: ios, video, app-thinning

I'm developing an universal iOS app and it has lot of video resources. In order to reduce the size of the app I would like to apply app thinning. I know that it's possible to do it with image resources but I haven't found any documentation about how to it with video resources. In other words, I would like to have video in different resolutions for iPhone and iPad devices.

Is it possible to do it with video resources?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you thought of the idea of streaming the video through API?

Comment: @SahebRoy I would my app to have offline capabilites and I would like to take advantage of app thinning

Comment: what is the size of your ipa? and the size of the whole video resources?

Comment: @SahebRoy ipa: ~520 MB,  Video resources: ~500 MB

Comment: A working demo of a solution for the problem of slicing a video asset issue can be found at this SO answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267037/is-slicing-a-video-attached-to-ios-app-assets-possible

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way currently to decrease size of the video assets drastically. 
You can look into [On Demand Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/) if it fits the bill.